# Final width of Imageview

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview

When I set an `ImageView` bitmap on create of an `Activity`. At what point can I read the final width of the `ImageView`?

What seems to happen is the bitmap is set in the `onCreate()` method and immediately is assigned the width of 965 which I can see when entering the onLayout method of the `ImageView`, then more of the layout/creation occurs and the `ImageView` width changes to 909 (I guess this is due to the adjustment to the screen size?).

What I want to do is read the final value of 909 to set the width of another view programmatically.

I've tried the `addOnGlobalLayoutListener` of the `ImageView` to try to listen of the completion of the layout, however reading the g`etMeasuredWidth()` method of the `ImageView` still returns the 965 value.

What is the final event called once the layout calculations are completing which will allow me to set the width of another view during the creation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wait for `Activity` window to be attached and then get the `ImageView` width. To do that, you can override [onWindowFocusChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onWindowFocusChanged(boolean)) method of the `Activity`:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus){
    int imageWidth = yourImageView.getWidth();
}
```

As a second suggestion:

You can also add a [OnPreDrawListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener.html) and use his [onPreDraw()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener.html#onPreDraw()) method

> At this point, all views in the tree have been measured and given a
>   frame

```
 ViewTreeObserver vto = yourImageView.getViewTreeObserver();
 vto.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
        public boolean onPreDraw() {
           int imageWidth = yourImageView.getMeasuredWidth();
           return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the final width in the `onStart()` once the `onCreate()` has finished.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that, but it seems that the onStart event occurs before the layout of the views.